# Androidx: Using a button in one fragment to navigate to another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to android development and have been in the process of developing my very first app and have run into what I understand as a very simple complication but I can not seem to solve it, and most online resources that I have come across have been outdated and include deprecated methods. That being said, onto the issue:

In my MainActivity.java I am using a side drawer navigation that allows me to move between fragments. Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_account:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AccountFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_goals:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new GoalsFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_progress:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProgressFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_food_diary:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FoodDiaryFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_nutrition:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new NutritionFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

The navigation between all of these fragments works perfectly. But my issue is that I have a button that exists on one of these fragments that I want to use to take me to another fragment that will not be accessible through the navigation drawer. Lets call this `fragment_profile`.
Will it be possible to navigate to this new fragment from an existing fragment using the onclick of a button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on to what Vikas said.
He told that when you need to go from an Activity to Fragment you need the `getSupportFragmentManager()` like below

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
}
```

Note how we need to pass in the class for `ProfileFragment()` here, its layout `fragment_profile` will be loaded on its own as you will be setting `ProfileFragment()` with `fragment_profile` layout.

Next you may in future want to go from one `Fragment` to another in which case you will only need to add `getActivity()` before the `getFragmentManager()`, so it would become

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
   
 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
}
```

Comment: I was trying to navigate from one Fragment to another so I added "getActivity()" and it seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

to put a fragment in a screen all you need is a fragmentmananger. as you can see in your code how you have changed when one of the option in the navigation gets clicked then you are calling

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
```

to replace the existing fragment with the selected one. exactly same when user clicks on the button like below.

```
//your click listener callback
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
   getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
}
```

the only thing you need to take care is that the host should have the fragment container `fragment_container` thats it.

Comment: I tried this as I thought it would be the most logical thing to do, but I still got an error. "Cannot resolve method". But I just added "getActivity()" first now and it seems to have fixed the error. Thank you.

Comment: yeah getActivity is needed to replace fragments in the activity from fragment, that i missed adding now.